# Website not working in IIS 7 using the IIS Manager

Tags: iis, server

I have Microsoft Windows server 2008 R2 and have the IIS 7 running.

I have coded a web application on a seperate laptop and would like to publish it now on my server (serves as AD, DNS, File Server, IIS) that runs locally and has no external access. We will be using the application internally only.

I have followed the steps to install a website on IIS, however, it does not work. Below are the steps I have done.

Created a folder hierarchy and pasted the code files there. (check below image. The code files are inside wwwroot)

[image: Folder Hierarchy created]

Create a new website from the IIS Manager as the below image.

[image: IIS Manager config]

The wwwroot folder has SYSTEM permission and it inherits the permissions from the parent. (Does it need to have other permissions?!?)

Whenever I visit the website, I get an error that the page is not found.

[image: error]

*UPDATE*

Upon @Ravi A's answer below, I have tried his steps as the below image, but the username is not found and the error persists.
[image: error in username]

Any ideas what is wrong?

windows iis website

Comment: Is mysite.local bound to your IP ?

Comment: At command prompt  ping `Mysore.local` and see which IP address responds.

Comment: @RaviA. what do you mean ?

Comment: @LexLi I get : C:\Users\Administrator>ping mySite.local
Ping request could not find host mySite.local. Please check the name and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a binding in your DNS i.e. ping mysite.local should resolve to the server IP, in your case since it's a intranet it should resolve to 192.168.1.253.

[See here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/adding-host-a-dns-records-in-windows-server-2008-r2) on how to do it. You need access to DNS Manager.

Also since you are not clear on DNS mapping leave the hostname empty and use machine name or IP to browse the site.

Comment: Whenever I ping, i get :  get : C:\Users\Administrator>ping mySite.local Ping request could not find host mySite.local. Please check the name and try again.

Comment: That's because your domain is not mapped to any IP. Your domain should resolve to your server IP.

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: See here  - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/adding-host-a-dns-records-in-windows-server-2008-r2 . You need access to DNS Manager.

Comment: Also since you are not clear on DNS mapping why not leave the hostname empty and use machine name to browae the site.

Comment: I have added all the necessary points in my answers. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for your feedback. I tried and getting this error where the DefaultAppPool is not present in the usernames. any ideas ? thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have application pool with name DefaultAppPool . Your issue has nothing to do with permissions also as it is wwwroot folder it has all necessary permissions to run your application.